# PresetReverb makes MediaPlayer silent

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm trying to add a PresetReverb to a MediaPlayer. The weird thing is that, without it, the audio plays normally. But if I add the PresetReverb, no sound is playing. Here's what I tried:

```
    mCurrentPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, song);
    PresetReverb pr = new PresetReverb(1, mp.getAudioSessionId());
    pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
    pr.setEnabled(true);
    mCurrentPlayer.attachAuxEffect(pr.getId());
    mCurrentPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
    mCurrentPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
    mCurrentPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> mCurrentPlayer.start());
    mCurrentPlayer.start();
```

Of course,
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>` is in my manifest